# xpath select elements between two nodes

Tags: xpath

This is my HTML:

```
<table dir = "rtl .......">
<tbody>
<script src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3"......>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=mc&rev=6"></script>
<script>..</script>
<tr>
  <td class = "d2"...>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <-- these elements
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>
  <td class = "d2"...>..</td>
</tr>
<script>..</script>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
```

How would I count or select all `<tr>` elements between the two `<td>` elements whose id is `d2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The xpath is going to be a long one so brace yourself:**

```
count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr/td[@class = 'd2']][count(.|//tr[following-sibling::tr/td[@class = 'd2']])=count(//tr[following-sibling::tr/td[@class = 'd2']])])
```

To select the actual nodes and not have just the count, simply remove the first count :

```
//tr[preceding-sibling::tr/td[@class = 'd2']][count(.|//tr[following-sibling::tr/td[@class = 'd2']])=count(//tr[following-sibling::tr/td[@class = 'd2']])]
```

There are various things happening here notably:

- Select start node by selecting preceding sibling's child node tr/td with id='2'
- Select end node by selecting following sibling's child node tr/td with id='2'
- Use kaycian method : http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9940e108 to get the intersection between the two nodes.

Comment: As of 18.02.2020 the link is dead.