# how to select elements between two tags

Tags: xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xpath select elements between two nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957480/xpath-select-elements-between-two-nodes)

based on this html i need two xpath expressions:

```
<table dir = "rtl .......">
<tbody>
<script src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3"......>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=mc&rev=6"></script>
<script>..</script>
<tr>
<td class = "d2"...>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <-- first expression should select these elements
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>
<td class = "d2"...>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <-- second expression should select these elements
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
<tr>..</tr> <--
</tbody>
```

how i can select all `<tr>` elements after the first `<td class = "d2"...>` tag with an xpath expression and all `<tr>` elements after the second `<td class = "d2"...>` tag with other xpath expression.

Comment: @Oded i only want to return the count of these elements for doing some thing.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What did you try? What xpath did you attempt?

Comment: i am miking an iphone app and create a tableView with sections and for every section i need to set the number of row in section to a specific value and because that i need to count these elements .i am using HPPLE to parse html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the intersection of two node sequences in XPath 2.0 like so

```
//table/tbody/tr[td/@class = 'd2'][1]/following-sibling::tr except //table/tbody/tr[td/@class = 'd2'][2]/following-sibling::tr
```

In that expression, you will get all the tr siblings that follow the tr that contains the first td of class d2, and then remove those that are after the second such tr.

Unfortunately, XPath 1.0 does not have the concept of an intersection of two node sets.  However, you can get the unions of two node sets in XPath 1.0 like so:

```
//table/tbody/tr[td/@class = 'd2'][1]/following-sibling::tr | //table/tbody/tr[td/@class = 'd2'][2]/preceding-sibling::tr
```

The following path will get you the tr nodes after the second tr that contains a td of class d2

```
//table/tbody/tr[td/@class = 'd2'][2]/following-sibling::tr
```

Comment: I updated the answer to show an alternative path when using XPath 1.0