# Getting nodes under a specific node element

Tags: xpath, htmlcleaner

I need help with my problem over here or at least some advice. I am parsing a HTML document using a HTMLcleaner with the use of XPATH.

I have something like this:

```
<html>

[code and other <h4> tags]

<h4>Random name</h4>
<a href="link" target="target"> Text I want to get </a>
<a href="link2" target="target2"> Text I want to get 2 </a>
<a href="link3" target="target3"> Text I want to get 3 </a>
<a href="link4" target="target4"> Text I want to get 4 </a>
<h4> Random name 2 </h4>
<a href="link" target="target"> Text I don't want to get </a>


[code and other <h4> tags]
</html>
```

Ok. I have several `<h4>` tags, each one of them with `<a>` tags and with the some text. My problem is that I don't know how to get all the respective the *text* from a specific , just like a "h4[i]". I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
String xpath = "h4["+number+"]//a" //where number will increment
```

Thank you in advice for you help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [xpath select elements between two nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957480/xpath-select-elements-between-two-nodes)

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/h4[1]/following-sibling::a[not(preceding-sibling::h4[2])]/text()
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/h4[1]/following-sibling::a[not(preceding-sibling::h4[2])]/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment, wrapped in a single top element to become an well-formed XML document):

```
<html>
    <h4>Random name</h4>
    <a href="link" target="target"> Text I want to get </a>
    <a href="link2" target="target2"> Text I want to get 2 </a>
    <a href="link3" target="target3"> Text I want to get 3 </a>
    <a href="link4" target="target4"> Text I want to get 4 </a>
    <h4> Random name 2 </h4>
    <a href="link" target="target"> Text I don't want to get </a>
</html>
```

**The Xpath expression is evaluated and all selected (text) nodes are copied to the output:**

```
 Text I want to get  Text I want to get 2  Text I want to get 3  Text I want to get 4
```

Comment: In my document this isn't the first h4, that's why I couldn't make it like this. I will have to go through all the all <h4> tags and get their content but not all at once, that's my problem. I will try and use something like h4[i], where my i will increment.

Comment: @AnTz, Then you must edit the question and provide a really representative XML document. Never leave the reader guess. And in my solution just replace `1` with `N` and `2` with `N+1` -- where `N` is the ordinal number of the occurence of `h4` in the children of its parent.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was a mistake, I couldn't provide the XML file though. Besides that, I've tried to get "/h4[4]" (this is how I queried for) and it provides me nothing. Also, trying "/h4[4]//a" didn't work as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AnTz, Without providing a representative (structurally the same) XML document, you are wasting your (and your readers') time. Of course, an XPath expression designed to select nodes from one document will generally *not* select the wanted nodes from another, stucturally dissimilar document.

Comment: This is the example I am encountering in the document. I didn't understand what you are trying to explain, I'm trying to get the nodes from another document by using those "/"?

Comment: @AnTz, The expression in the question is wrong -- it tries to select all `a` *descendants* of `h4`, but none of the `h4` elements have any descendants at all. You need to read a good book on XPath and get to understand at least the basics.